# More elegant way to implement

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate

```
ArrayList<Boolean> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(true, false, true, false, false, true));

List<String> filter = Arrays.asList("TRUE");
List<String> filter = Arrays.asList("FALSE");
List<String> filter = Arrays.asList("TRUE","FALSE");

if (!filter.isEmpty()) {
    List<Boolean> collect = values.stream()
            .filter(i -> i ? filter.contains("TRUE") : filter.contains("FALSE"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(collect);
} else { System.out.println(values);}
```

With filter values `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `TRUE,FALSE` I get the desired result `[true, true, true]`, `[false, false, false]` and `[true, false, true, false, false, true]`. In case of an empty filter, the list should be returned as is. "TRUE" or "FALSE" may represent any String..

Is there a more elegant way to implement?

Comment: Wrong site for improving working code. Better asked at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why are your filter values strings? Could you not map them to `Boolean`? What do you mean by "any String"? Is this code working as expected? I'm not certain from your question.

Comment: `filter(b -> filter.contains(b ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"))` would be an improvement

Comment: How does this compile?

Comment: @Joe The 3 `filter` declarations are alternatives. The 4th alternative is an empty list.

Comment: @Joe For some reason OP has chosen to show three possible values for `filter`, which is part of why I am unclear on the question.

Comment: The definition of `filter` as in your question doesn't really work unless you tend fo perform the next block of code for `filters` which would then be a `List<List<Boolean>>`. that said, it could, of course, have been, betterr to construct `List<Set<Boolean>>` to perform a `contains` and which might further be not required given you would have shared a proper use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. test for emptiness inside the predicate (unmeasurably small performmance cost)
2. use a ternary for the contains value

Thus eliminating the `if-else` and the extra call to `contains()`:

```
List<Boolean> collect = values.stream()
        .filter(i -> filter.isEmpty() || filter.contains(i ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(collect);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the filter can truly only be the 4 valid combinations, then you can cheat:

```
if (filter.size() == 1) {
    Boolean removeTrue = filter.contains("FALSE");
    values.removeIf(removeTrue::equals);
}
System.out.println(values);
```

Comment: Pretty neat! I already tried with a predicate but never arrived here..

Comment: Is there an advantage in speed when using removeIf instead of let the stream make a new list instance?

Comment: @tli You asked for "more elegant way", not faster way. Unless the list is huge, you won't notice a difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the goal is here but elegance could be in the eye of the beholder so, here you go.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(go(
            Arrays.asList(true, false, true, false, false, true), 
            Arrays.asList("TRUE")));
}

static List<Boolean> go(final List<Boolean> values, final List<String> filter) {
    if (filter.isEmpty())
        return values;
    return values
            .stream()
            .filter(i -> filter.contains(i.toString().toUpperCase()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Filter criteria could be any string, means that true should match e.g to "X" and false to "Y".